# v-if not Updating with Global Function Regarding Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuejs2

In a .vue view I have the followign line of code:

```
<p v-if="this.$cookies.logged()">Some text</p>
```

and in main.js the function mentioned above is defined:

```
Vue.prototype.$cookies = Vue.observable({
  logged: function(){
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${'initSession'}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2 && parts.pop().split(';').shift() == 'true') return true;
    else return false;
  },
});
```

However, the `v-if` does not update with the function i.e. when the function returns `true` the paragraph is not shown.

How may I solve this?